# How to fetch and reuse GraphQl schema

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I have two aws lambdas. One of them implements apollo graphql server. Second lambda needs dynamically to fetch schema, to take some specific queries and apply for them custom resolvers. How to achieve it? Is there some practice and/or code samples. I need to make kind of proxy graphql lambda without rewriting schema manually.

Comment: It should expose a __schema variable

Comment: directly request the schema endpoint (post an introspection query to the same url)